# Applying Meta Analysis findings to predict future outcome

Tags: predictive-models, simulation, meta-analysis, meta-regression

Can Meta Analysis results be used to predict the future outcome? If yes, how?

I am reviewing a Meta Analysis Report (I haven't prepared this report). It is about the treatment of hypertension in elderly patients. It has endpoints like stroke, heart failure, mortality, etc. Risk ratios are provided for each endpoint. The mean age of patients at baseline is provided.

Now my questions are:

1. Can I combine "baseline mean age" & "risk ratio at follow up years" to predict outcome (e.g., the chance of stroke) age-wise? If yes, how?
2. If no, what further inferences I can draw from this report?

Comment: Your question is quite generic. We need more input. Is it a pairwise meta-analysis? A network meta-analysis? Are you pooling only randomized trials? In addition, what do you mean when you say you would like to 'combine "baseline mean age" & "risk ratio at follow up years"? You could stratify your meta-analysis according to study average age, but that would be all, unless you prefer to do meta-regression.

Comment: It is a pairwise meta analysis.

Comment: It is a pairwise meta analysis. The meta analysis is based on 10 studies. The study period is of 10 years.                                                  I am interested to find if different age groups have different risk ratios. But I only have mean ages of patients per each study at the start of the trial. For example Study 1 Age Range (55-70 ) Mean age of patients for intervention (61+/-5 ) Mean age of patients for control (62.3+/-5). Risk ratios are available for 5 years & 10 years

Comment: I would do a simple pairwise meta-analysis with meta or metafor in R, stratifying by median age group. You can create 3 or 4 strata, depending on how many studies end up in each stratum. Then simply look at the amount of total heterogeneity that is explained by such stratification Otherwhise, you can do a meta-regression with metafor, using average age in each study as moderator. Note though that this will be weak evidence, as power is very limited, whereas the risk of ecological fallacy and regression to the mean may be substantial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comment!  If possible, could you please share some resources that explain these concepts in detail? (Especially meta regression using average age)

Answer (score 1):

To draw together the information in comments (mostly from user @Joe_74).

The answer to the problem is meta-regression. You include study mean age in your meta-analysis model as a moderator, preferably as a continuous moderator but categorised if you insist. Note however that this does not tell you whether older patients are more likely to benefit from the treatment in terms of their risk of stroke (or other outcome). What it does is to tell you whether being enrolled in a study with on average older patients improves your chances when treated. These are not the same.